# How to effectively handle the problem of installing WordPress locally for each new project?

Tags: installation, localhost

I waste a lot of time installing WordPress then populating it with dummy stuff for each new project. I started creating a new theme for each project (instead of creating a whole new install) but it's not good either since each project has its own specifics in terms of content.

Is there a time-saving, professional solution for this problem?

Comment: There are _many_. I would recommend to elaborate on what else had you considered and possibly tried and how it didn't fit your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run a [multisite](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) setup for developing, it saves time and you can just delete the sub-site when you're done developing.

I also have a few different .xml files of common content types that I tend to use a lot (Portfolio items, Standard pages / posts, Testimonials, etc.) and I just [import](http://codex.wordpress.org/Tools_Import_Screen) each one as and when I need it.

Answer (score 1):

By creating a [multi-site](http://codex.wordpress.org/Glossary#Multisite) installation.